# iphone sdk how to implement carousel (coverflow) view in phone gap?

Tags: jquery, ipad, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phone gap for iPad application development and i need to implement Coverflow in my window. How do I implement this? Is there any sample code?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad to be reasonably answered on Stack Overflow (please [see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)). Search for some tutorials, do some work on your own and if you hit a particular stumbling block, ask then.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

Comment: iCarousel doesn't look like it interfaces with phone gap in any straightforward way

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can find a native plugin for phonegap that gives you native iOS coverflow, you're probably best off using a javascript coverflow-like UI.  For example:

- [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) looks good
- [Zflow](http://code.google.com/p/css-vfx/wiki/AboutZflow) has a busted demo but claims to do this